# Open a Form in a Panel from a Form inside that Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I want to open a form inside a panel, but I want to open that form from a form that is already inside that panel.
example: the name of my panel is panel and I have 3 forms, form1, form2, form3.

```
panel.Controls.Clear();
form2 myForm = new form2();
myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
myForm.TopLevel = false;
myForm.AutoScroll = true;
panel.Controls.Add(myForm);
myForm.Show();
```

now I want to open form3 with a button inside form2

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    form3 myForm = new form3();
    myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    myForm.TopLevel = false;
    myForm.AutoScroll = true;
    panel.Controls.Add(myForm);
    myForm.Show();
    this.close();
}
```

so how do I add a new form to a panel inside a other form and close the current one

Comment: When you close the parent form, all of its child forms will also get closed, so you either just need to hide the form2 whilst form3 persists or just make form2 a child of the panel

Comment: so how do you hide form2 and then show form3

Comment: @TaW With TopLevel false it can be.  Granted, not necessarily recommended.

Comment: Wow, Lars, you are right. Always more to learn..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispose of everything that's in your panel first and *don't* call `this.Close();` (that will close your current form):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  Panel p = this.Parent as Panel;

  if (p != null) {
    while (panel.Controls.Count > 0) {
      panel.Controls[0].Dispose();
    }

    form3 myForm = new form3();
    myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    myForm.TopLevel = false;
    myForm.AutoScroll = true;
    panel.Controls.Add(myForm);
    myForm.Show();
    // this.Close();
  }
}
```

Calling `panel.Clear();` does not dispose of the controls, and can be a memory leak if you keep adding and clearing forms and controls without ever disposing them.

Edit:

After re-reading your question again, you need to reference the parent property to get the current panel:

```
Panel p = this.Parent as Panel;
if (p != null) {
  form3 myForm = new form3();
  myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  myForm.TopLevel = false;
  myForm.AutoScroll = true;
  p.Controls.Add(myForm);
  myForm.Show();
  this.Close();
}
```

In this case, yes, you can call `this.Close()` from Form2 because that will only close that form.